# Custom encoding for nested structure

Tags: json, swift

This question is about how to write `Encodable` definition for a custom nested struct I have. I have defined a JSON request struct as follows:

```
   //Define type of request - get or set
    enum ReqType: String, Codable {
        case get,set
    }
    //For get request, define what request we can make
  enum GetReq: String, Codable {
        case getPage,getOther
    }
    

    //Request structure - reqBody for now is set to GetReq type
    // to keep it simple, no sum type over GetReq and SetReq for now
    struct Req {
        var reqType: ReqType
        var reqBody: GetReq
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case reqType
        }
    }
    
    //An incomplete attempt at encoding logic
    extension Req: Encodable {
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            try container.encode(reqBody, forKey: .reqType)
        }
    }
```

Now, given a request say `Req(reqType: ReqType.get,reqBody: GetReq.getPage)`, we want to encode it as `{"get":"getPage"}`. That is, key is the string value of `ReqType` enum, and value is the string value of `GetReq` enum. My code above can't encode string value of `ReqType` enum as key. So, it ends up encoding as `{"reqType":"getPage"}`.

Will appreciate help with fixing the code to achieve the encoding where the key is string value of the enum.

Comment: See if https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/01/23/codable-enums/ helps, also I think there is a new feature for enum codable in Swift 5.4 or Swift 5.5 (beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want `ReqType` to be the key of the JSON, conform that to `CodingKey`, instead of `Codable`:

```
enum ReqType: String, CodingKey {
    case get,set
}
```

Now you can do

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ReqType.self)
    try container.encode(reqBody, forKey: reqType)
}
```

In case you also need a `Decodable` implementation:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ReqType.self)

    // picks the first valid ReqType, in case the JSON has multiple keys
    if let key = container.allKeys.first {
        reqBody = try container.decode(GetReq.self, forKey: key)
        reqType = key
    } else {
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(GetReq.self, .init(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "No request body found!"))
    }
}
```